# Hooking up AC/DC converter

Tags: ac, ac-dc, step-down

[the converter in question](http://www.current-logic.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=35_43&products_id=373)

Hello for the converter in the link above when converting AC to DC should I have both inputs to the same AC source or do I just need one output connected? I have used the above with DC to DC successfully but I don't want to damage the component with an AC source. The two input wires are not shorted together. And I appologize but I was not able to find the datasheet for this converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked page says the thing can accept 16 - 40 Volts DC or 16 - 28 volts AC input.  Apply your supply voltage (AC or DC) across the two input wires.  Since it can take an AC input, polarity doesn't matter when using DC.